# how to add blinking "_" after each character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://codepen.io/-dhaval-/pen/yMJKgE

above is the link of where i am trying this...

below is code:

```js
function typeAp(target, toType, stepTime){
  var n = 0;
  var chars = Array.from(toType);
  setInterval(function(){
     $(target).append(chars[n]);
      n++; 
    
  },stepTime);
};

typeAp('.init',"initializing",100);
```

```css
body{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.cmd{
  background-color:#111;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:20px;
  
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
}
p{
  letter-spacing:2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family:courier;
  color:lime;
}
::selection{
    background:#111;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cmd">
      <p class="init">$Robot~ </p>
      <p class="perc"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to add blinking "_" after each character so that it looks like the text is typed and it feels like command line.

Suggest any mistakes, or extra things i could add to this code if u like.

Comment: Here you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpGyYo (text is added to a `span` inside the `p`, which is followed by an animated `span` containing the cursor)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure `jQuery` solution, but it can also be done by css.

I've added a `callback function` to your `typeAp` and it insert the "_" and makes it blink.

This trigger the callback when its done writing.

```
if (n == chars.length) {
    callback(target)
}
```

```js
function typeAp(target, toType, stepTime, callback) {
  var n = 0;
  var chars = Array.from(toType);
  setInterval(function() {
    $(target).append(chars[n]);
    n++;
    if (n == chars.length) {
      callback(target)
    }
  }, stepTime);

};

typeAp('.init', "initializing", 100, function(target) {
  $(target).append("<span class='blink'>_</span>")

  function blinker() {
    $('.blink').fadeOut(500);
    $('.blink').fadeIn(500);
  }

  setInterval(blinker, 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cmd {
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}

p {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: courier;
  color: lime;
}

::selection {
  background: #111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cmd">
      <p class="init">$Robot~ </p>
      <p class="perc"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pseudoelement` and simple animation:

```
.init::after {
  content: '_';
  display: inline-block;
  animation: flash 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes flash {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/Rpordx)

Answer (score 0):

Add the cursor to your HTML:

```
body
  .container
    .cmd
      p.init
        span.prompt $Robot~ 
        span.cursor _
      p.perc
```

Style the cursor:

```
.cursor {
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {  
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

And change the JS to target the new `span`:

```
typeAp('.prompt',"initializing",100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to styles

```
  .init::after {
  content: '_';
  animation: blink 0.2s linear infinite;
  }

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opaicty: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with jQuery:

```js
function typeAp(target, toType, stepTime){
  $('.dash').hide();
  var n = 0;
  var chars = Array.from(toType);
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $(target).append(chars[n]);
    n++;
    if (n >= chars.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('.dash').show();
    }
  },stepTime);
};

setInterval(function() {
  $('.dash').toggleClass('hide');
}, 700);

typeAp('.text',"initializing",100);
```

```css
body{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.cmd{
  background-color:#111;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:20px;
  
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
}
p{
  letter-spacing:2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family:courier;
  color:lime;
}
.dash.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
::selection{
    background:#111;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cmd">
      <p>
        $Robot~ <span class="text"></span><span class="dash">_</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS and pseudoelement `:after`

```js
function typeAp(target, toType, stepTime){
  target = $(target).addClass('typing');
  var n = 0;
  var chars = Array.from(toType);
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    target.append(chars[n]);
    n++;
    if (n >= chars.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      target.removeClass('typing');
    }
  },stepTime);
};

typeAp('.init', "initializing", 100);
```

```css
body{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.cmd{
  background-color:#111;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:20px;
  
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
}
p{
  letter-spacing:2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family:courier;
  color:lime;
}
.init:not(.typing)::after {
  content: '_';
  animation: blink 1s ease .5s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
::selection{
  background:#111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cmd">
      <p class="init">$Robot~ </p>
      <p class="perc"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```